# how do I concatenate 3 lists using a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

In python, how do I concatenate 3 lists using a list comprehension?

Have:

```
    list1 = [1,2,3,4]
    list2 = [5,6,7,8]
    list3 = [9,10,11,12]
```

Want:

```
    allList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

I tried using a list comprehension, but I'm not very good at them yet.  These are what I have tried:

```
    allList = [n for n in list1 for n in list2 for n in list3 ]
```

this was a bad idea, obviously and yielded len(list1)*len(list2)*len(list3) worth of values.  Oops.  So I tried this:

```
    allList = [n for n in list1, list2, list3]
```

but that gave me allList = [list1, list 2, list3] (3 lists of lists)

I know you can concatenate using the + operator (as in x = list1 + list2 + list3)but how do you do this using a simple list comprehension?

There is a similar question here: [Concatenate 3 lists of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906032/concatenate-3-lists-of-words) , but that's for C#.

Comment: I can't see the benefits of doing that :S

Comment: Can you explain what benefit you think you're getting from using a list comprehension?  I think you must have some misconception regarding what they do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A better solution is to use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) instead of addition. That way, instead of creating the intermediate list `list1 + list2`, and then another intermediate list `list1 + list2 + list3`, you just create the final list with no intermediates:

```
allList = [x for x in itertools.chain(list1, list2, list3)]
```

However, an empty list comprehension like this is pretty silly; just use the `list` function to turn any arbitrary iterable into a list:

```
allList = list(itertools.chain(list1, list2, list3))
```

Or, even better… if the only reason you need this is to loop over it, just leave it as an iterator:

```
for thing in itertools.chain(list1, list2, list3):
    do_stuff(thing)
```

---

While we're at it, the ["similar question" you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906032/concatenate-3-lists-of-words) is actually a very different, and more complicated, question. But, because `itertools` is so cool, it's still a one-liner in Python:

```
itertools.product(list1, list2, list3)
```

Or, if you want to print it out in the format specified by that question:

```
print('\n'.join(map(' '.join, itertools.product(list1, list2, list3))))
```

Comment: +1 for `list(something)`; surprised this isn't used more often.

Answer (score 15):

Here are some options:

```
>>> sum([list1, list2, list3], [])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

>>> list1 + list2 + list3
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

With comprehension: (it's really not necessary)

```
>>> [x for x in  sum([list1, list2, list3], [])]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Thanks for `sum([list1, list2, list3], [])`. I wanted to avoid using itertools just for one line in my code. Not that avoiding was a priority. This help. Area there any caveats to this? Is itertools faster?

Comment: awesome [x for x in  sum([list1, list2, list3], [])]

Answer (score 0):

You can do `allList = list1 + list2 + list3` instead of `allList = [x for x in list1 + list2 + list3]`

Answer (score 0):

If you put the lists that you want to concatenate in a list literal, you can write a nested for loop in the list comprehension to loop over all elements.

```py
allList = [n for l in [list1, list2, list3] for n in l]
```

This solution does not need any extra imports or other functions to concatenate the lists.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to all of the other options, you could also just splat them all into a new list for comprehension (if you don't explicitly require a comprehension to generate the concatenated list):

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> list3 = [9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> allList = [*list1, *list2, *list3]
>>> allList
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I couldn't come up with any reason why the new list would need deriving from a comprehension explicitly since you could just nest this inside a comprehension if desired, e.g. if you had other logic to run on the merged list:

```
>>> [val + 3 for val in [*list1, *list2, *list3]]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

If performance is a big deal, you can also just make the splatted list a generator function instead:

```
>>> [val + 3 for val in (*list1, *list2, *list3)]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do list1 + list2 + list3

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list2 = [5,6,7,8]
>>> list3 = [9,10,11,12]
>>>
>>> list1 + list2 + list3
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

If you want to remove duplicates, run below code:

```
>>> list(set(list1 + list2 + list3))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```